# Create edittext like stackoverflow tag text box

Tags: xamarin.android, tags, multiline

I want to create a multi lined edit text that can hold buttons but also have the ability to add free form text.

It should behave like the tag text box of stackoverflow that is under the body of the question when you ask a question on stackoverflow.

I thought about one layout that holds buttons (e.g. tags) and an edit text right after said layout. But as I want it to be multi-lined and if there was a line break, I'm not sure how the edit text should behave, since it couldn't be a quadratic box anymore.

Can you point me in the right direction? I've seen a post about making parts of an edittext uneditable. I could do this and put buttons over it, but the buttons might be a little bigger than the underlying text.

Do you know of alternatives?
I hope you get the point, if not I'll draw the control.

Comment: I would suggest you update the question with a proper image of what you want.

Comment: Yeah, by using a spannable string inside an edittext

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same by using [FlowLayout](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout). Keep on adding text/button view it will automatically wraps contents to next line